# Connect to a browser with Pyppeteer

Tags: python, pyppeteer

I want to connect to a chrome browser that i have started with the launch command

```
await launch(headless=False, \
            executablePath ="C:/Program Files/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe",\
            args=["--remote-debugging-port=9222"])
```

with the connect command

```
browser=await pyppeteer.connect(browserURL='http://127.0.0.1:9222')
```

but it looks that this is not right.

if i open the browser with command line

```
chrome_path = 'C:/Program Files/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe '
cmdCommand = chrome_path + " --remote-debugging-port=9222"
subprocess.Popen(cmdCommand.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

then pyppeteer.connect works fine.

Comment: i corrected the typo from --remote-debuggins-port to --remote-debugging-port

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether you are using python or javascript or any other tools, e.g. puppeteer-stealth package, you need to first launch and then get the `wsEndpoint` and connect it via `pyppeteer.connect`

```py
pup = await launch(headless=False, \
            executablePath ="C:/Program Files/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe",\
           );
endpoint = pup.wsEndpoint()

pyppeteer.connect(browserWSEndpoint = endpoint )
```

if you are trying to connect by specifying --remote-debugging-port, you have a typo on the option.

Comment: endpoint = pup.wsEndpoint() is working fine but launch with --remote-debugging-port still doesn't work, even if i have first open the browser with commacd line or not, i get "Browser closed unexpectedly"

Comment: it is pup.wsEndpoint not pup.wsEndpoint()

Comment: are you on the same host or you are trying to access from remote? why don't you just use wsendpoint?